# Hive InputOutput in vanilla version hadoop 2.5.1

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am facing the following error while executing MapReduce job in Linux(CentOS). I added all the jars in classpath. The database name and table name already in the hive database with some column of data in the table. Then also I can't able to access the data from the hive database table.
I'm using vanilla version of hadoop for work. Should i need to edit hive-site.xml file by mysql driver path, username and password for hive?. if yes please tell me the procedure to add username and password for hive.
I placed all dependency files inside the hive and MapReduce prog and also im using vanilla version of Hadoop for the calculation purpose. and also i'm getting

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.

while executing

> hive --service metastore

```html
 murali]# hadoop jar /home/murali/workspace/hadoop/HiveInputForMapper/target/HiveInputForMapper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver -libjars $LIBJARS 
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /hadoop/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/12/02 18:53:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/12/02 18:53:09 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
14/12/02 18:53:10 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
14/12/02 18:53:10 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
14/12/02 18:53:10 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
14/12/02 18:53:13 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
14/12/02 18:53:13 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: MySQL check failed, assuming we are not on mysql: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO DataNucleus.Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
14/12/02 18:53:15 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
14/12/02 18:53:16 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
14/12/02 18:53:16 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_databases: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck
14/12/02 18:53:16 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_databases: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 
14/12/02 18:53:16 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=cpr_transaction
14/12/02 18:53:16 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=cpr_transaction 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.cpr_transaction table not found)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:97)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:71)
 at com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver.run(HiveInputDriver.java:26)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
 at com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver.main(HiveInputDriver.java:49)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.cpr_transaction table not found)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1560)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.get_table(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:997)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTable(HCatUtil.java:191)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:105)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
 ... 10 more
```

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question title

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a configuration issue. Are you sure you have configured the hive-site.xml correctly ?
This is file from which the Hive cli client picks up the metastore url and connects to execute queries.
Also i see that you hive cli is trying to connect to 'default' db. Is that the DB where your table is ?

Comment: Ya i'm using default DB only for accessing, hive-site.xml i configured and also im attaching this one below...

Comment: this is the link [link](https://github.com/MuralikrishnaGS/hive-site-xml-file/blob/master/hive-site.xml)